# what is user timezone from twitter?

Tags: json, twitter

I have a JSON format tweet data. One attribute is user location where you can see the place user lives. However many people say it is not enough to prove that user is from that place. I also see there is called user.time_zone. But could not find officially find an explanation what is user timezone, even from twitter website.

Could Anyone help me to answer what is user timezone? Is it timezone where user from?

```
"user" : {

                "profile_sidebar_fill_color" : "DDEEF6",
                "geo_enabled" : true,
                "created_at" : "Wed Jun 08 06:20:33 +0000 2011",
                "contributors_enabled" : false,
                "time_zone" : "Brisbane",
                "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "C0DEED",
                "translator_type" : "none",
                "is_translator" : false
        }
```

Comment: The [official documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object) is amazingly unhelpful in this case… 

Comment: Yeap.。thats what I said, Can't see anything from twitter website ；（

Comment: when was that Tweet and user object retrieved? In the majority of cases, `time_zone` and `utc_offset` are now always marked as null in the data, per [this announcement](https://twittercommunity.com/t/upcoming-changes-to-the-developer-platform/104603). Previously, it referred to the timezone that the user had set in their profile settings.

Comment: Hi Andy. The data was retrieved in April this year. Because the tweets were retrieved by region (for example, all posts from the gold coast ) And I am trying to identify is the user local or from international. Thats why I hope to get some information by user location or user timezone

Answer (score 1):

As Andy said in the comments, timezones are not given any more. Even when they were, they weren't very helpful.  There are dozens of countries which use Central European Time, for example.

You cannot assume that a user has filled in their data correctly. I quite often choose "Dublin" as my timezone instead of "London", because it is alphabetically first in a drop down menu.

The only other way to see where a user claims to be, is by looking at any geotagged posts. Although even these can be faked.

Comment: Thank you, Terence.  Originally, I thought it is easy to recognize a user just by looking into their user location or time zone. But it seems like it is not accurate either.   The reason why I wanted to user location is I retrieved tweets using location and would like to see are they local or international. They might just post one post in this area (e.g goldcoast) so I am trying to find a method to identify is the user local or not. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: It depends on how you define "local".  I live in one city, but work in another - which one is my "local" city? I regularly have meetings in a different country and sometimes stay for a week. Does that make me local?  Best you can do is look through their tweets and assess how many different locations they post from.

Comment: I would say where you are living will be considered as a local. In my case, I am trying to see are you from Australia or from overseas